# Connect to SQL Server CE Database online

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, connection-string

I have created a C# Windows application that connects to a local SQL Server CE database file. This is working fine, however I would like to expand the application and allow it to run for multiple users.

My idea is to place the SQL Server CE database online in some private hosting and connect to it from the local application. I have been looking at this for some time know and have not yet been able to find a solution on the net.

Is this possible? And if not what would you suggest is the simplest solution to achieve the same result?

Comment: SQL Server CE is a **file-based** approach - you don't have an *instance* of SQL Server running. It's really not designed for remote, multi-user scenarios - if you need that, use the real SQL Server, e.g. SQL Server Express (configure it to support remote connections) or SQL Server Web Edition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sql Server CE is not designed to do this.  You cannot connect to a Sql Server CE database over a network connection.

If you a truly want to use SQL CE, then instead of having your application directly connect to it, write a Web API / Web Services that provides the `Data Layer` and each application can use those to do DB Calls.

Really this should just be replaced by Sql Server Express (or higher), then use the same idea above.

Comment: I have no ties to SQLCE, so this can change. So if I change to SQL Server Express, I should just be able to connect to it over a network connection? i.e the connection string would be something like 'http://mywebsite.com/databasefile.mdf ?

Comment: If the database is on the internet, it would be an extremely bad idea to open the port.  It's best practice to create an API in front of the database, that typically include authentication, authorization, business rules etc.